# Eclipse Neon on Linux: no console for C/C++ programs

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

With Eclipse 4.6.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.1 I'm having trouble getting the console to work with C/C++ programs.  When I run my program from a shell, it produces output on stdout and stderr and accepts input from stdin.  However, when I "Run as C/C++ Appplication" in Eclipse, the console doesn't seem to work — standard output and error never appear, and there's no place to supply input.

Has anyone seen this?  Any idea why it's happening?  It's worth noting that Java applications that use the console work fine, so this is specific to C/C++ somehow.

Source code: [image]

Compiler settings: [image]

Run configuration: [image]

Comment: Did you try flushing stdout? I faced a similar problem with older versions of Eclipse and Ubuntu. For some reasons the output was not flushed after `\n`.

Comment: @Gerhardh I just tried adding fflush(stdout) and fflush(stderr) but still no console.  (I'm pretty sure this would be redundant with stderr anyway, but it never hurts to try. :))

Answer (score 0):

There may be so many reasons for your problem but i will give you some to do list in order to solve your problem.

1) Please build your C/C++ code before you run it. You can do it via Ctrl+B button combination or by clicking on menu.

2) Be sure that you have one main function in your current project and there is no debugger errors.

3) The reason why your code is working on shell but not in Eclipse may be that your Eclipse might not know your compiler's name or path. You can check this case by following this path :

Click File on menu -> Click properties -> Expand "C/C++ Build" -> Click on "Settings".

In the opening screen you have to see gcc/g++ compiler is set properly and  Command line pattern is true and working on Eclipse.

If you give more detail about your Eclipse version or some screenshots, we can help you more precisely.

Also i reccomend using "Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers" version of eclipse in this link : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplersr2

When you install this version, probably you will not need to set so many settings to work on your projects.

Edit: That's the example usage of fputs.

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   FILE *fp;

   fp = fopen("file.txt", "w+");

   fputs("This is c programming.", fp);
   fputs("This is a system programming language.", fp);

   fclose(fp);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Steps 1–3 look good.  I'll attach a few screenshots of relevant dialogs.  Any version information you're looking for beyond 4.6.2?

Comment: You are using fputs in your source code. Fputs does not write anything to console. It just writes your string into file that is sent to fputs in second argument. In your case, it's normal that there is nothing appear in console. Just use "printf" in order to see your result in console.

Comment: fputs() writes to whatever FILE* you pass as the second argument, which in this case is stderr.  Consider it similar to fprintf(), but without the extra behavior of formatting placeholders like "%d" and "%s".